# Semicolon missing after extracting DDL via ksh script

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, ksh

After running the following script the semicolons are missing at the end of the statements in the output file. How can I have the semicolon printed out as well? In this case there should be a semi colon after `AUTO` and after `RESIZE 146800640`

```
sqlplus -s sys/${sysPwd}@${srcSID} as sysdba<<-EOF>createTS.sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LONG 9999
SET LINESIZE 999
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 350
SET PAGESIZE 10000
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLESPACE','$srcTablespace') FROM DUAL;
quit;
EOF
```

Cat resulting file : createTS.sql

```
CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE "TSName" DATAFILE
'/hostname/db/SID/oradata1/tsname.dbf' SIZE 5242880
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5242880 MAXSIZE 32767M
LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE
'/hostname/db/SID/oradata1/tsname.dbf' RESIZE 146800640
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the [SQLTERMINATOR setting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#BGBJBFGE) from its default false value to true, which you can do with an anonymous PL/SQL block before your query:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
END;
/
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLESPACE','$srcTablespace') FROM DUAL;
```

Or you can use the `exec` SQL*Plus shorthand but the whole call has to be on a singe line.

See [the `dbms_metadata` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66910) for more about the `set_transform_param` procedure.

Comment: Thanks that did it