# Copying comments from schema of one table to another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables enrollment and enrollment_aud with exactly same columns. I want to copy comments used in enrollment table schema to enrollment_aud. How can I do that without explicitly writing COMMENT ON TABLE for 73 columns

Comment: `CREATE TABLE enrollment_aud LIKE enrollment;` copies comments too.

Comment: Note that tables with large numbers of columns can sometimes be indicative of poor schema design.

Comment: When I am executing the following query in SQL developer i am getting the error:Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE enrollment_aud LIKE enrollment
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: If your database is MySQL (you tagged your question with `mysql`), why does it throw an Oracle error message (ORA-00922)? If you mistagged your question, please fix it (use the grey "Edit" link), so that Oracle experts can find your question and help you.

Comment: Why do you have two identical tables?  This suggests a poor design.

Answer (score 1):

Exctract the comment definition from the first table (e.g. using SQL Developer TABLE SQL)

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN "XXX"."ENROLLMENT"."COL1" IS 'My col1';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "XXX"."ENROLLMENT"."COL2" IS 'My col2';
```

Edit the script replacing the table name with the new table and run it

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN "XXX"."ENROLLMENT_AUD"."COL1" IS 'My col1';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "XXX"."ENROLLMENT_AUD"."COL2" IS 'My col2';
```

You can *script* it with the `dbms_metadata` package as well. Example

```
select 
  replace(dbms_metadata.get_dependent_DDL('COMMENT','ENROLLMENT'),'"ENROLLMENT"','"ENROLLMENT_AUD"') 
from dual;
```

which returns the updated script for the new table.

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN "XXX"."ENROLLMENT_AUD"."COL1" IS 'My col1';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "XXX"."ENROLLMENT_AUD"."COL2" IS 'My col2';
```

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36181452/4808122) how to add the semicolon if it is missing